# With PHP what would be faster: multiple DB connection class instances or a singleton?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am working a new PHP project that calls upon a records class to update the database. Currently every object or script that needs to do so makes a new instance of the object. In theory this could mean as many as six or seven instances per call.

The design currently calls for the object to connect to the database in the constructor method which would mean between 0 and 7 connections?

For the demo I will be using only MySQL but as it is all tucked away behind a single interface one imagines that it could easily be ported to other data stores (and probably will).

Given the nature of the project speed of response is the key optimisation point however with so many connections do I run the risk of overloading the system when demand is high and therefore slowing everything down anyway?

Is this a situation when it would simply be better (and faster overall) to use a singleton?

Or is there some way to have my cake and eat it?

Comment: As a general rule, you don't create a DB connection to move each twig in the anthill. You can easily have a static class variable to handle the connection, and each instance do as it pleases with it. The PDO interface does a pretty good job of standardizing DB management, so that would be my tool of choice if multiple DB engines might be supported.

Comment: Having to establish a new connection on every DB operation is not only terribly inefficient but a sign of bad design. Use dependency injection to pass a single instance of your DB connection object to every object that needs it. And by single instance, I mean single instance, not a singleton, BTW.

Comment: This was my general impression too. That said I was slightly worried about being accused of premature optimization.

Comment: @lafor - Could you show sample code for creating a "dependency injection" for PDO or mysqli_*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A connection to a database server takes time to connect and will consume memory. Also the number of connections a database server will accept at the same time is limited. That's why the number of connections should be kept as small as possible which means that only a single connection to the same database should be used.

Using just a single connection means not that you have to use the `Singleton` pattern. Simply create the connection object somewhere at the start of the script and pass it to components which will execute DB queries.

Comment: Thank you. You have confirmed my fear that something very silly was in danger of happening. I am looking at ways I can make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you two solutions:

1. Use stored procedure if you can, it will decrease # of Mysql connections, its more safety, and its cached.
2. Use at first time Mysql connection and than save data into Redis or Memcached.

It intend to your queries and your needs.

Thanks

Comment: stored procedures are cached separately for each connection / thread in MySQL! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/sp-cache-sp.html

Comment: I know, he can make stored procedure that include more that single query. This step will decrease # of Mysql connections

Comment: (true, though in my opinion there are more arguments against then for stored procedures, but thats a different story). It is just that you stated stored procedures are cached in MySQL, which is true but in a very strange and pretty useless manner. Its a common misconception that I wanted to warn others about.

Comment: @Pevara "It intend to your queries and your needs." - It means if you have process that can be in one stored procedure its better than nasty single queries, this solution doesn't suitable for any situation. if the queries around same process / close entities you can pack it in single store procedure. according to option #2 it will good if you need data every time like online users or something like that.

Comment: Quibble over terminology:  Having multiple statements in a Stored Procedure does not decrease the number of "connections"; it merely decreases the number of "round trips" to the server.  You have to have a "connection" in order to call the SP.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this solution](https://github.com/wake-up-neo/php-xconn). It uses singleton approach for each connection and  handles multiple connections across multiple adapters (e.g. mysql, memcached etc.)